# Progress for Data Table

Tags: web, data-tables, progress-bar

Users are accustomed to viewing data within a data table. The problem is the user cannot complete one action until another action is completed. Is there a better way to lay this out, but also give the use an indicator of where they are within the process. I tried showing each section on an individual screen, but based on the user - the recommendation is to use a data table.[image: User selects company]
[image: Users selects role]

[image: Users Permissions]

Answer (score 1):

I personally like this type of view, as it is similar to the Azure/Google Analytics view but I may not be in the target user group. Some users may feel it is too cluttered. Have you considered doing some user testing to get feedback on this? Also maybe some user research to build this UI out in a manner similar to an interface your users are familiar with. I like to emulate interfaces my users are familiar with based on my personas. If the primary persona is an experienced admin, this may be the exact thing you/they are looking for.

Comment: Well this is a redesign of the current screenshots I posted. The part that was confusing for myself was the users not having understanding of having to choose a company first before being ale to add the role the permissions.

Comment: Maybe hide the roles and role properties until a user selects a company and a message on the screen saying `Select Company`

Comment: Thanks i'll try that idea :)